# Can I restore only selected files from Time Machine Backup after a fresh OS X re-install?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, backup, time-machine, restore

I'm thinking to reinstall my Mac OS X on my Macbook Pro and starting fresh (instead of recovering from a Time Machine backup)

The question is:

If I do that, after OS X is reinstalled, will I be able to pick only certain files to be restored from my Time Machine backup?

The scenario is basically I want to start with a fresh OS X install and restore my iTunes library and possibly a few other documents.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do a fresh OSX re-install.

After that go into Time Machine and restore what you need.

Comment: That is exactly what I wanted. So it is possible.